# Remove all text values if search textbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone help me ...how to remove all values from my name(textboxes) if the `search` `textbox` is clicked? my current code wont work help me guys please.

html code:

```
<input class="search_textbox" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="search" id="query" onChange="removeText()" />
<input class="search_form_input" placeholder=" 1.)" name="name1" id="name1" readonly type="text" />
<input class="search_form_input" placeholder=" 2.)" name="name2" id="name2" readonly type="text" />
```

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeText(){
$(".search_form_input").val('');
}
</script>
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.search_textbox').on('click', function(){
        $('.search_form_input').val('');
     });
});
```

After reading your comment I realized you're probably talking about removing the placeholder values. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.search_textbox').on('click', function(){
        $('.search_form_input').attr({placeholder: ''});
     });
});
```

Comment: i tried ur code if i click the search texboxe still the  the name textboxes wont clear.

Comment: @user3340637 check it out again. Are you wanting the placeholder removed? If so, the code above should work.

Comment: @user3340637 Great! Can you select this as the answer then? Thanks.